# mysql remove only specific text from rows

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have about 40k rows which have Colname StreetView and they are links generated like: https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&oi=plus&q=https://maps.google.com/maps?q&layer=c&z=17&iwloc=A&sll=38.107502,-122.569211&cid=2903161686038478822&cbp=13,12.7,0,0,0&cbll=38.107395,-122.569241&ved=0CA0Q2wU&sa=X&ei=IFFeUd_QCemaiQLY8IC4Cw&gl=US&hl=en

what i need is to remove this -> https://www.google.com/url?sa=D&oi=plus&q= from each row soo i will have in rows only https://maps.google.com/maps?q&layer=c&z=17&iwloc=A&sll=38.107502,-122.569211&cid=2903161686038478822&cbp=13,12.7,0,0,0&cbll=38.107395,-122.569241&ved=0CA0Q2wU&sa=X&ei=IFFeUd_QCemaiQLY8IC4Cw&gl=US&hl=en ... 
Is there anyway to do something like that? I am using program sqlyog to manage db soo if there is way with sql statements i would like to solv it, or should i use php and use functions like replace and stuff..?

Comment: specificated - I learned a new word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName SET
       StreetView=Replace(StreetView,SUBSTRING_INDEX(StreetView,'https://maps',1),'')
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8769/1)